# Using ImportPhotos Plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-plugins, import, photos, geotag

I have some geotagged photos saved on a network drive which I want to import into QGIS 3.2. I have installed the [ImportPhotos](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ImportPhotos/) Plugin.

I have gone through the import photos process and selected the input folder location and output folder location. But when I click on the path to the photo it keeps trying to take me through internet explorer to open the link (which it obviously can't open)instead of taking me to my photos on the network drive.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include - what syntax did you use to specify the output folder location? Did it actually output photos to that location? What's the syntax of the path you're clicking on?

Comment: QGIS 3.4 does this naively > https://communityhealthmaps.nlm.nih.gov/2019/02/21/mapping-field-photos-in-qgis/

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out by @Mapperz this is supportet natively now in QGIS since 3.4.
Unfortunately the link he posted is not working any more.

I found this to be a good description: https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/8/23/mapping-and-viewing-geotagged-photos-in-qgis

The documentation for the tool can be found here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#import-geotagged-photos

Does this solve your problem?